# OpenSSL Windows x64 Compilation error

Tags: windows, 64-bit, compilation, openssl

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile OpenSSL 1.0, 64 bit:

```
    ias -o tmp32\ia64cpuid.obj tmp32\ia64cpuid.asm
'ias' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'ias' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

Does someone know what can I do?
(I do it on Windows 2008 x64 OS)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the former problem - I just added to the Path environment variable the path of ias:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\x86_ia64.

But after all I compiled it for x64 (VC-WIN64A) with NASM and it worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You've probably chosen VC-WIN64I (as an argument for the `perl Configure` command), which is a wrong platform in your case and will give a compilation error if you try to compile OpenSSL for  Windows 64-bit (x86-64 also known as AMD64). You should have passed VC-WIN64A. "I" stands for "Itanium" and "A" still stands "AMD64".

Run

```
perl Configure VC-WIN64A
```

and then run "nmake" again, it should work this time.

Answer (score -1):

I normally get my OpenSSL windows builds from [here](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). The guy who runs the site has the 64 bit version built so may be able to help if you email him. He's also looking for beta testers I think.

Comment: They don't have OpenSSL 1.0 yet.

Answer (score -2):

Forget all that building - its a nightmare!  Someone has done all the hardwork for Win7 64 and kindly put it here

https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip&can=2&q=