# ias is not recognised by visual studio command prompt

Tags: visual-c++, openssl, nasm

Am trying to install openSSL on my HP250 G4 running windows 7 64x
i downloaded it from the official GitHub and followed the install documentation
it asked to download Virtual Studio, Perl 5 with 2 modules, Make, NASM compiler, MinGW
i have no idea and never worked with those programs because am a web developer, and the cost of learning all of them just for the sake of installing openSSL is high
those are the command lines i run

```
perl ./configure VC-WIN64I
```

and

```
nmake
```

i got an error saying `ias` is not recognise as internal command, code from nmake u1077.
i have reviewed this answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753960/openssl-windows-x64-compilation-error)
that suggested to add the path to nasm.exe in the installation folder to the environment variable PATH after the `;`
then rebooted the command prompt and still nothing
i guess what needs to be achieved is to let visual studio command prompt invoke NASM compiler so that it recognises `ias` as a command, i googled it and found nothing
any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

You must use VC-WIN64A to compile openssl for Intel processors.
Don't forget to remove intermediates files with a **nmake clean**  before **nmake**

Comment: i thought VC-WIN64A is for AMD and VC-WIN64I is for intel, the A stands for amd and the i stands for intel
i cleaned the nmake and the 32 version worked instead VC-WIN32

Comment: WIN64I denotes IA-64 (Intel Itanium) and WIN64A denotes x86-64 also known as x64, x86_64, AMD64 and Intel 64